# two same line batch-file - only one line is woking

Tags: batch-file, pyqt

Every line is working by itself. But only first line is working if they are in the same file.

```
pyuic4 C:\file1.ui -o C:\file1.py
pyuic4 C:\file2.ui -o C:\file2.py
```

What is wrong?

It is Windows.

And pause did not working in this file. It just end after first line (but it is executed right)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Psychic debugging: `pyuic` is a batch file.

Use

```
call pyuic4 C:\file1.ui -o C:\file1.py
call pyuic4 C:\file2.ui -o C:\file2.py
```

instead.